# build Spring batch project with required parameters

Tags: java, maven, spring-batch

I don't understand how i should build a Spring batch project that needs some parameters in input with Maven.

I'm new to Spring batch and Spring in general honestly, so i was trying to follow along with an example in the "The Definitive Guide to Spring Batch" book, chapter 4.

The job requires some parameters and needs to validate them, i should launch the project from command line like this:

```
java –jar demo.jar fileName=test.csv
```

I need of course to build the `demo.jar` but when executing the tests, maven complains saying that the required parameters are missing.

I tried the following without success:

1. `./mvnw clean package -Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--fileName=test.csv`
2. `./mvnw clean package -Drun.arguments=fileName=test.csv`
3. `./mvnw clean package -DfileName=test.csv`

So the required parameter here is `fileName` and its extension needs to be validated.

How can i pass the required parameters to Maven in order to pass the tests and build the jar?

Thank you

---

This is the code i have:

MainClass:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class Project04Application {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public CompositeJobParametersValidator validator() {
        CompositeJobParametersValidator validator = new CompositeJobParametersValidator();
        DefaultJobParametersValidator defaultJobParametersValidator = new DefaultJobParametersValidator(
                new String[] { "fileName" }, new String[] { "name", "currentDate" });
        defaultJobParametersValidator.afterPropertiesSet();
        validator.setValidators(Arrays.asList(new ParameterValidator(), defaultJobParametersValidator));
        return validator;
    }

    @Bean
     public Job job() {
         return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("basicJob")
             .start(step1())
             .validator(validator())
             .incrementer(new DailyJobTimestamper())
             .build();
     }

    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").tasklet(helloWorldTasklet(null, null)).build();
    }

    @StepScope
    @Bean
    public Tasklet helloWorldTasklet(@Value("#{jobParameters['name']}") String name,
            @Value("#{jobParameters['fileName']}") String fileName) {
        return (contribution, chunkContext) -> {
            System.out.println(String.format("Hello, %s!", name));
            System.out.println(String.format("fileName = %s", fileName));
            return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Project04Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

TestFile:

```
@SpringBootTest
class Project04ApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        System.out.println("spring boot init");
    }

}
```

DailyJobTimestamper.java:

```
public class DailyJobTimestamper implements JobParametersIncrementer {

    @Override
    public JobParameters getNext(JobParameters parameters) {
        return new JobParametersBuilder(parameters).addDate("currentDate", new Date()).toJobParameters();
    }

}
```

ParameterValidator.java:

```
public class ParameterValidator implements JobParametersValidator {

    @Override
    public void validate(JobParameters parameters) throws JobParametersInvalidException {
        System.out.println("Parametri: " + parameters.toString());
        String fileName = parameters.getString("fileName");
        if (!StringUtils.hasText(fileName)) {
            throw new JobParametersInvalidException("fileName parameter is missing");
        }
        
        if (StringUtils.endsWithIgnoreCase(fileName, "csv")) {
            throw new JobParametersInvalidException("fileName doesn't have the csv extension");
        }
    }
    
}
```

If i remember correctly, the spring-boot test is there just to check if the application can start or not, but as soon as the application is starded during this test the job gets executed as well, the job then fails because there are no parameters as requested.

Any help please?

Comment: Building your job should be independent of how it is launched. If you can show the tests that are causing the issues, we can help with you there but it sounds like your tests are not structured correctly.

Comment: As Michael said, there are something wrong in your test. Input and output on unit test usually are known in advance. Share us your Test with lines in which you need the input parameter

Comment: I have no more files in this project, that's all. The only test that i have is the one in the `TestFile`